# Multiple unspaced tags appear as one continuous link

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

As seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299072/428543):

> [image]

Here's the view on web.

> [image]

Comment: "fixed" by adding spaces, but agree the bug better be actually fixed on the app side.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the Android app makes the tag links not in well the bubble form ([bubbles](/questions/tagged/bubbles)) but the normal underline form (a link for example). Since the user listed five tags with ***no space in between each tag***, it shows as one continuous link on the Android app.

Comment: Actually, the tags were in the form `[tag:chemistry]`. But yeah, there were no spaces.